# mySQL error datetime value error for str_to_date?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, datetime

This error comes from this code which i can't figure out whats wrong;

**#1411 - Incorrect datetime value: '11:00 PM' for function str_to_date**

```
CREATE TABLE OWNS (
STUDNO       NUMERIC(9) NOT NULL,
ENAME         CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
TYPE          CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
OTIME         TIME,
ODATE         DATE,
ODRTN         VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT OWNS_FOREIGN_KEY FOREIGN KEY (STUDNO) REFERENCES STUD(STUDNO));

INSERT INTO OWNS (STUDNO, ENAME, TYPE, OTIME,ODATE, ODRTN)
VALUES(123456789,'The Lion King','Anti', str_to_date('11:00 PM', '%l:%i 
%p'), STR_TO_DATE('16-jan-2011', '%d-%b-%y'), 3)
```

Appreciate the help thanks!!!

Comment: I can't reproduce the error here http://rextester.com/EHMAU46480 - Instead I get an error fpr using `%y` which should be `%Y`.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO OWNS (STUDNO, ENAME, TYPE, OTIME,ODATE, ODRTN)
VALUES(1234456789,'The Lion King','Anti', str_to_date('11:00 PM', '%l:%i 
%p'), STR_TO_DATE("16-jan-2011", "%d-%b-%Y"), 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try '%h:%i %p' as your mask for the time instead. I've always used '%h' for hours.